# Downloading multiple csv files with Selenium/Chrome & Python

Tags: python, csv, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having an issue downloading multiple files with Chrome using Selenium & Python. I do the below loop, but only find the last file 'clicked on' in my downloads folder (using Mac):

```
for x in range(4): 
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",sub_elements[x])  
    print(sub_elements[x].get_attribute('innerText').strip())

    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
            EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, 'selectedMonth'), 
    sub_elements[x].get_attribute('innerText').strip() ))                                           

    driver.find_element_by_id("exportCsv").click() #
```

After googling, I tried changing the browser options as below but it did not work:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This exportCsv sounds like a RPC, that takes time to execute. This is just a  theory, but might worth a try.

Bit of background: once you click on a link, a request is sent. If you click on a different link before any kind of response would arrive to the first request, the first request is cancelled. What seems to happen here is that you click so fast that you cancel your first three requests, and only the last one goes through (I guess it might take a second or two before you would actually get a response).

After clicking, try to wait till the download starts. (I don't think there is WebDriver method for this, but you could for example observe the number of files in the Download folder) Or just sleep 5 seconds between clicks, as a quick and dirty test.

---

As a side note, perhaps grabbing the download link (maybe along with the cookies) from the browser, and downloading them separately without the browser would be more reliable (lot of things can go wrong with downloads using Selenium, too many variables).

Comment: If the last download is working, it seems that you can download without big hassles (at least at the first sight). After you click on link1-3, does it start loading, or does anything happen? Do you get the 3rd file if you decrease the loop range, and don't click the last one?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I don't see any URL, or anything related to your question...unless you are merging multiple CSVs from a folder on your desktop.  If that's the ask, I have a few solutions for you...but you seem to be doing this from the web...  Anyway, check out this solution.  Hopefully this gets you going in the right direction, but again...I can't tell what you are doing...

```
ad <- read.csv("http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv")
head(ad)
```

Here is a way to reference multiple PDF files from a URL, and download each.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

url <- "https://www.bot.or.th/English/MonetaryPolicy/Northern/EconomicReport/Pages/Releass_Economic_north.aspx"
page   <- getURL(url)
parsed <- htmlParse(page)
links  <- xpathSApply(parsed, path="//a", xmlGetAttr, "href")
inds   <- grep("*.pdf", links)
links  <- links[inds]
```